# Will code execute through multiple label definitions sequentially?

Tags: c

This may be a dumb question, and I'm shocked I had trouble Googling it, but here goes:

What happens in this situation:

```
int foo(void){
     char x = 1;

     if (x == 1}
         goto apple;
     }
     else{
         goto banana;
     }

apple:
    printf("apple");

banana:
    printf("banana");

    return 0;
}
```

If `x==1` will the output be

```
 apple
 banana
```

Or will it just be `apple` and stop at the end of the label? Like will the code continue to be executed line by line and enter the other label?

Comment: http://ideone.com/ is great for this kind of thing, you can test simple things like that really quick

Comment: for example: http://ideone.com/ZRrGzE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If x==1 will the output be

```
 apple
 banana
```

Yes, it will. Labels (either `goto` or `switch` labels) fall through.